# Error - VBA Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to coding and am trying to perform the following;

Tracking Workbook contains project information which is taken from an input workbook. I am trying to open the input workbook copy all the data on the project info sheet and past it in the tracking workbook's project info sheet.Here is my coding below

```
Sub GetProjectInfo()

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="\\ccprd02\workgrp2\AM\SPIM Input.xlsm"
    ActiveSheet("Project Info").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("SPIM Tracking Sheet.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveSheet("Project Info").Select
    Cells.Select
    Range("A1").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Windows("SPIM Input.xlsm").Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close

End Sub
```

It is opening the file ok but then seems to stop just before copying the data. I can't seem to pinpoint the error. I have searched several threads with similar issues but have no had any luck. Is there something wrong with my coding?

Comment: Qualify your objects with `set`.

Comment: @findwindow - What objects? The whole sub is based upon Select, Activate and ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: Workbooks, sheets and cells are not objects?

Comment: Only if they are vars that have been dimmed as a worksheet type or range type and then they need to be `Set` to a worksheet or range of cells.

Comment: Enrico - see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Ooooh. I see what you mean now. The variable is the object.

Comment: @findwindow the `Set` keyword is used for assignment.  There is no assignment in this code.  (The assignment operator is `=`, which does not appear at all.)

Comment: Heh. I never considered it a two step process but makes sense it is.

Comment: @findwindow - it's not that the variable is the object. A workbook / worksheet / cell is always an object. However, the only time you would use `Set` is when you want to assign an object to a variable of that same object type. *edit - maybe you already understood that, but just thought it was worth making clear, based on your previous comment*

Comment: Scott's more articulate than Jeeped /me hides Edit: the clarification is great. It's not a distinction I ever truly thought about.

Comment: Thank you all! It is working now. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 8):

The problem with your code is in the second line.

```
ActiveSheet("Project Info").Select
```

This should be,

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Project Info").Select
'alternative
Worksheets("Project Info").Select
```

As mentioned in my comment, see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals. The [ActiveWorkbook property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821871.aspx), [Application.ActiveWindow property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835855.aspx), [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) are just not reliable methods of referrencing.

Comment: nice way to point out a main issue without manipulating the original code more than needed :) *needed being relative, of course :)*

Answer (score 4):

When writing VBA code, you are best served by qualifying all objects with variables and working directly with the objects themselves.

Try this:

```
Dim wbC as Workbook
Dim wbP as Workbook
Dim wsC as Worksheet
Dim wsP as Worksheet

Set wbP = Workbooks("SPIM Tracking Sheet.xlsm")
Set wsP = wbP.Sheets("Project Info")
Set wbC = Workbooks.Open (Filename:="\\ccprd02\workgrp2\AM\SPIM Input.xlsm")
Set wsC = wbC.Sheets("Project Info")

wsC.Cells.Copy wsP.Range("A1")

wbC.Close False 'assuming you want to close the workbook you opened.
```

I also wonder if you really want to copy **every cell** of the worksheet or do you just want to copy cells with *actual data*?

If you just want cells with actual data, you can use `wsC.UsedRange.Copy wsP.Range("A1")` *Note - this could have issues as well, but I will let you tell me if it does :)*